# Mysterious Benedict Society and The Prisoner's Dilemma

Tags: riddle, mystery

“The answer to this riddle has a hole in the middle,
And some have been known to fall in it.
In tennis it's nothing, but it can be received,
And sometimes a person may win it.
Though not seen or heard it may be perceived,
Like princes or bees, it's in clover.
The answer to this riddle has a hole in the middle,
And without it, one cannot start over.”

This is a riddle that comes from Trenton Lee's book, The Mysterious Benedict Society and the Prisoner's Dilemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Love is the answer but what's the point of posting such a popular riddle?

The answer to this riddle has a hole in the middle,

> the letter O has a hole in it

And some have been known to fall in it.

> One can fall in love

In tennis it's nothing, but it can be received,

> love means 0 in tennis scoring

And sometimes a person may win it.

> You can win somebody's love

Though not seen or heard it may be perceived,

> You can't really see it or hear it

Like princes or bees, it's in clover.

> Princes are metaphorically “in clover,” an idiom for “wealthy,” bees are literally in clover for nectar, and the word “love” is in the word “clover.”

The answer to this riddle has a hole in the middle,

> as above

And without it, one cannot start over.”

> The hole in question is the letter O and you can't start the word over without O